# how to check if bounding box contains my point

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, coordinates, bounding-box

I wanna know if my point is in my bounding box using coordinates:

point to check:

CLLocation -> 48.847172 2.386597

bounding box :

maxLat minLat / maxLon minLon

```
"48.7998602295",
"48.8198640442",
"2.46138595581",
"2.48138619423"
```

how can i check that ?

Comment: side note for checking if a radial area contains a CLLocation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLRegion_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009575-CH1-SW9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would [`CGRectContainsPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectContainsPoint)

```
bool CGRectContainsPoint (
  CGRect rect,
  CGPoint point
);
```

work for you?

You can convert a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` into a `CGPoint` like this:

```
CGPoint p = (CGPoint) { loc.latitude, loc.longitude };
```

Comment: I would consider writing a wrapper function which takes the CLLocation and calls CGRectContainsPoint after creating a CGRect and CGPoint from the input.

Comment: how do you convert a CLLocationCoordinate2D to a CGRect ?